# Group all keys in dict that have identical values, when the values are lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict:

```
my_dict = {
  'train_1': ['a', 'b','c'],
  'train_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  'train_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  'train_4': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
  'train_5': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  'train_6': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}
```

I need to find all keys in the dict that have identical lists.

The **output** should be:

```
{
  'group_1': ['train1'],
  'group_2': ['train_2', 'train_3', 'train_6'],
  'group_3': ['train_4'],
  'group_4': ['train_5'],
}
```

I can use something like this for the task when the values in the dict are not lists:

```
flipped = {}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(value)
    if value not in flipped:
        flipped[value] = [key]
    else:
        flipped[value].append(key)
```

But how can I achieve this when the values are **lists**?

Comment: You can't. Dictionary keys cannot be mutable objects. You could convert the lists to tuples and use those instead. If you want to do this, then inside the `for` loop before adding to dictionary, add `if isinstance(value, list): value = tuple(value)`

Comment: If your keys should be the strings `group_1`, `group_2`, etc (according to the required output you shoed), why does your code attempts to use the list themselves as keys?

Comment: Anyway, your code will work with lists if you change `flipped[value]` to `flipped[tuple(value)]` and `if value not in flipped` to `if tuple(value) not in flipped`

Comment: @DeepSpace This leads to the error "unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: @Cybernetic it does not if you change `value` to `tuple(value)`

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: @Cybernetic please read my comment and make the changes again. It works.

Comment: Ahh I missed it in the if statement. Thanks. I just need to have groups as keys in the final result rather than the lists, but I can figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, you could change the lists to tuple and then use them as the keys:

```
my_dict = {
  'train_1': ['a', 'b','c'],
  'train_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  'train_3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  'train_4': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
  'train_5': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
  'train_6': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}

flipped = {}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if tuple(value) not in flipped:
        flipped[tuple(value)] = [key]
    else:
        flipped[tuple(value)].append(key)
print(flipped)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c'): ['train_1'], ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): ['train_3', 'train_6', 'train_2'], ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'): ['train_5'], ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
: ['train_4']}
```

**EDIT**:

once, filtered. you could iterate over the new dict and assign the desired keys:

```
grouped_dct = {}
i = 1
for k,v in flipped.items():
    grouped_dct['group_' + str(i)] = v
    i += 1
```

print(grouped_dct)

OUTPUT:

```
{'group_1': ['train_4'], 'group_2': ['train_5'], 'group_3': ['train_2', 'train_6', 'train_3'], 'group_4': ['train_1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

if order of element in the list matters then below should work for you.

```
flipped = {}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(value)
    newVal = ''.join(x for x in value)
    if newVal not in flipped:
        flipped[newVal] = [key]
    else:
        flipped[newVal].append(key)
print(flipped)
```